# What is the recommended place to install nodejs and mongodb in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, nodejs, mongodb

I was trying to install node js in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , First I have downloaded latest distribution from [Nodejs_Official_Page_Link](https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.11.1/node-v9.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz) .It got downloaded at my Downloads folder.then I have copied it from Download folder to `/usr/local/` Directory through following command:

```
sudo cp -r node-v9.11.1-linux-x64 /usr/local/
```

After that I have checked my `/usr/local/` Directory and it showed me a folder name `node-v9.11.1-linux-x64`

After that I have tried to set the path through following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Then I have added `:/usr/local/node-v9.11.1-linux-x64/bin` in PATH

then I checked it through `node --version` and it showed me `v9.11.1`
& for `npm --version` it is `5.6.0`

then I tried to run `npm i -g node-static` and it said permission error ,try it as root.I know it can be done with `sudo` then.

So my question is that `/usr/local/` a correct choice to install Node-js or should I install it somewhere else?

Further I also want to know what is the recommended place to install mongodb?I am new to Ubuntu so want to go with the recommended/safe practices suggested by experienced developers.Thankyou!

Comment: the recommended way for mongodb is `sudo apt-get install mongodb`

Comment: For Node.js, you can use their repository. See this: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/how-to-install-and-configure-nodejs-and.html it explains installing from their repository as well as setting the PATH correctly.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend installing via supported packages rather than copying files into `/usr/local` manually. For MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/. For Node: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall.

Comment: @Stennie        I know it would be easy to install through packages but as I have already installed it by copying it to `/usr/local` directory so want to resolve this permission issue .I first thought as through `sudo` it will be done but it didn't work with `sudo` so can you please suggest me how to resolve this permission issue , I tried following command and it didn't work : `sudo npm i -g node-static` which  responded as  `sudo: npm: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new on Ubuntu and I installed node few weeks ago.

> is that /usr/local a correct choice to install Node-js or should I
>   install it somewhere else ?

I think that /usr/bin/ is not a bad place to install nodeJs, however keep in mind that other users on your computer won't have access.

> I am new to Ubuntu so want to go with the recommended/safe practices
>   suggested by experienced developers.

According to the documentation : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions , you should ensure that you've complete all the "manual steps".

I suggest you to use [nodesource github repository](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) for automated installation.

Comment: I know it would be easy to install through packages but as I have already installed it by copying it to `/usr/local` directory so want to resolve this permission issue .I first thought as through `sudo` it will be done but it didn't work with `sudo` so can you please suggest me how to resolve this permission issue , I tried following command and it didn't work : `sudo npm i -g node-static` which  responded as  `sudo: npm: command not found`

Comment: If you want to run Node with manual installation, you should be able to fix your permission issues if you follow the steps described here : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: thanks for your reply , Did you install mongodb ,if yes then what is the recommended place for same ?

Comment: Not yet, however I'm planning to use MongoDB for my next project. I recommend you to install using repertory. You have a sort of tutorial here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

I am installing nodejs and npm 10 using this instructions:

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

and installation runs without any problem !

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.